# Cannot connect to mysql group replication instance on openshift

Tags: mysql, openshift, mysql-group-replication

I have deployed a MySQL server (bitnami helmchart) to an openshift cluster (version 8.0.25-debian-10-r16) and made a group replication cluster using docs here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-replication.html

The Mysql server bootstraps the group replication without any problems:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM performance_schema.replication_group_members;
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+----------------+
| CHANNEL_NAME              | MEMBER_ID                            | MEMBER_HOST   | MEMBER_PORT | MEMBER_STATE | MEMBER_ROLE | MEMBER_VERSION |
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+----------------+
| group_replication_applier | be431342-8366-11ec-bea6-ea1fb6641f44 | mysql-0       |        3306 | ONLINE       | PRIMARY     | 8.0.25         |
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

and now I want to join another MySQL instance on a VM, to do so, first I create a `LoadBalancer` service to access the MySQL ports outside of the openshift cluster. And I can telnet both `3306` and `33061` from the VM. But when I create replication users on the Mysql instance on the VM and start the replication with `START GROUP_REPLICATION USER='rpl_user', PASSWORD='password';` I get the below error on the vm's logs:

```
[ERROR] [MY-011735] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] Timeout while waiting for the group communication engine to be ready!'
[ERROR] [MY-011735] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] The group communication engine is not ready for the member to join. Local port: 33061'
[ERROR] [MY-011735] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] The member was unable to join the group. Local port: 33061'
[ERROR] [MY-011640] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: 'Timeout on wait for view after joining group'
[ERROR] [MY-011735] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] The member is already leaving or joining a group.'
[ERROR] [MY-011735] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] Timeout while waiting for the group communication engine to be ready!'
[ERROR] [MY-011735] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] The group communication engine is not ready for the member to join. Local port: 33061'
[ERROR] [MY-011735] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] The member was unable to join the group. Local port: 33061'
```

The VM's IP address is in the whitelist of the MySQL deployed on openshift and I don't see any errors on the Mysql's pod

Here is the Mysql configuration on the openshift:

```
    [mysqld]
    disabled_storage_engines="MyISAM,BLACKHOLE,FEDERATED,ARCHIVE,MEMORY"
    server_id=1
    gtid_mode=ON
    enforce_gtid_consistency=ON
    binlog_checksum=NONE
    plugin_load_add='group_replication.so'
    group_replication_group_name="aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa"
    group_replication_start_on_boot=off
    group_replication_local_address= "mysql-0:33061"
    group_replication_ip_allowlist= "172.16.0.0/12"
    group_replication_group_seeds= "172.16.60.5:33061,172.20.1.223:33061"
    group_replication_bootstrap_group=off
    bind-address=0.0.0.0
    default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password
    skip-name-resolve
    explicit_defaults_for_timestamp
    basedir=/opt/bitnami/mysql
    plugin_dir=/opt/bitnami/mysql/lib/plugin
    port=3306
    socket=/opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock
    datadir=/bitnami/mysql/data
    tmpdir=/opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp
    max_allowed_packet=16M
    bind-address=0.0.0.0
    pid-file=/opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysqld.pid
    log-error=/opt/bitnami/mysql/logs/mysqld.log
    character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
    character-set-server=utf8mb4
    collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

    [mysql]
    default-character-set = utf8mb4

    [client]
    port=3306
    socket=/opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock
    default-character-set=utf8mb4
    plugin_dir=/opt/bitnami/mysql/lib/plugin

    [manager]
    port=3306
    socket=/opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock
    pid-file=/opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysqld.pid
```

Mysql configuration on the VM:

```
[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
server_id=2
gtid_mode=ON
enforce_gtid_consistency=ON
binlog_checksum=NONE
plugin_load_add='group_replication.so'
group_replication_group_name="aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa"
group_replication_start_on_boot=off
group_replication_local_address= "mysql-1:33061"
group_replication_ip_allowlist= "172.16.0.0/12"
group_replication_group_seeds= "172.16.60.5:33061,172.20.1.223:33061"
group_replication_bootstrap_group=off
default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password
skip-name-resolve
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp
port=3306
socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
tmpdir=/tmp
max_allowed_packet=16M
bind-address=0.0.0.0
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
character-set-server=UTF8
collation-server=utf8_general_ci

[client]
port=3306
socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
default-character-set=UTF8

[manager]
port=3306
socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Here `172.16.60.5` is the loadbalancer IP for MySQL on openshift and `172.20.1.223` is the IP of MySQL on the VM, both of them can see each other on ports `3306` and `33061`

Comment: You should attach effective configuration for both instances in question, th eprblem might lie in addressing. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49837554/mysql-group-replication-timeout-while-waiting-for-the-group-communication-engin

Comment: @Andrew I update the question